# Legend is not displaying all active features/layers in ArcGIS Pro using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, legend, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool

I created a script tool that positions the north arrow, legend, scale bar, and title in a layout; and then zooms to a bookmark and exports the layout as a PDF. But when I go and look at the PDF, the legend does not display the graduated color symbology from the results of a summarize with-in, but will display one of my point layers. However, when I go and look at the layout in ArcGIS Pro the graduated color symbology is displayed in the layout legend.

Here is the custom script tool I'm using:

```
import arcpy

#input layer
lyr = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

# input name of layout
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
lyt = p.listLayouts("Layout_King")[0]

# Reposition the scale bar
scaleBar = lyt.listElements("MAPSURROUND_ELEMENT", "Scale Bar")[0]
mf = scaleBar.mapFrame
scaleBar.elementPositionX = mf.elementPositionX + 0.0
scaleBar.elementPositionY = mf.elementPositionY - 0.5

# Reposition the north arrow
northArrow = lyt.listElements("MAPSURROUND_ELEMENT", "North Arrow")[0]
mf = northArrow.mapFrame
northArrow.elementPositionX = mf.elementPositionX + 8.8
northArrow.elementPositionY = mf.elementPositionY + 0.7

# Align the title with the center of the map frame
title = lyt.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT", "Name of Map Text")[0]
mf = lyt.listElements('MAPFRAME_ELEMENT',"Map Frame")[0]
title.elementPositionX = mf.elementPositionX + (mf.elementWidth / 3.7)
title.elementPositionY = mf.elementPositionY + (mf.elementHeight / 0.98)

# Reposition the Legend and fix legend title
legend = lyt.listElements("LEGEND_ELEMENT", "Legend")[0]
legend.title = "Legend"
legend.elementPositionX = mf.elementPositionX + 4.8
legend.elementPositionY = mf.elementPositionY + 6.15

# setting layout to bookmark
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("Current")

# add name of layout
lyt = aprx.listLayouts("Layout_King")[0]
mf = lyt.listElements("MAPFRAME_ELEMENT")[0]

# add name of bookmark
bkmks = mf.map.listBookmarks()
bkmks.sort(key=lambda x: x.name, reverse=True)
for bkmk in bkmks:
      mf.zoomToBookmark(bkmk)
      lyt.exportToPDF(r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Exports" + "\\" + bkmk.name + ".pdf")
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or missing?

Also I'm using this custom script tool ModelBuilder

I tried using `legend.updateItem()` and `legend.updateItem("*")`, but it gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'LegendElement' object has no attribute 'updateItem'
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to updateItem on the legend element http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/LegendElement/00s300000041000000/ to force it to refresh between zoomToBookmark and exportToPDF.

Comment: I tried that, but it gives me the following error. `AttributeError: 'LegendElement' object has no attribute 'updateItem'`

Comment: OP is using ArcGIS Pro, I dont see `updateItem` on `LegendElement` http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/legendelement-class.htm That will be an arcpy.mapping (ArcMap) property only.

Comment: Simply as a guess (I'd have to test to know for sure), this could be an exporting issue. The help for `LegendElement` mentions how it works dynamically with the map contents. `arcpy.mp` does not have the same refresh commands that `arcpy.mapping` did. Everything is supposed to be responsive. It might be a bug, it might not be designed to work with exporting, it might be some trivial to make it work.

Comment: Please present a [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) rather than your whole code.  For example, the north arrow looks like it would be unrelated to the issue that you describe so your code could be simplified by removing that.